# Двойной цикл range based for по шаблонным классам

Tags: c++

Есть шаблонный класс

```
template<typename It>
class PAGE {
private:
    It begin_, end_;
public:
    PAGE(It begin, It end) : beg_(begin), end_(end){
    }
    It begin() {
        return begin_;
    }
    It end() {
        return end_;
    }
};
```

Он содержит интервал определенных элементов. И есть класс, который создает классы PAGE, забрасывая их в массив:

```
template<typename Iterator>
class Paginator {
public:
    Paginator(Iterator begin, Iterator end, size_t page_size){
        // Лишний код удален для понятности, но тут он делит переданный интервал и превращает в PAGE
    }

    const Iterator begin() const {
        return pages.begin();
    }
    const Iterator end() const {
        return pages.end();
    }

private:
    vector< PAGE<Iterator> > pages;
};
```

И ожидается, что при попытке проитерироваться по страницам циклом

```
Paginator<vector<int>::iterator> paginate_v(v.begin(), v.end(), 6);
for (const auto& pageTest: paginate_v) {
    for (int& x : pageTest) {
    }
}
```

Второй цикл будет использовать ф-ции `begin()` и `end()` в классе `PAGE`, но переменная `pageTest` почему-то становится типом int, а не классом `PAGE<vector<int>::iterator>`.  В чем проблема? Документацию по циклу уже читал, но это не особо помогло

Comment: Проблему только что понял - я в возвращаемом функцией типе поставил Iterator, теперь проблема другая - какой тип поставить в возврат? vector<PAGE<Iterator>>::iterator не принимает

Answer (score 1):

Все, проблема решена, я ошибся с возвращаемым типом,нужен был

`typename vector<PAGE<Iterator>>::iterator`